# Flask y Javascript

Tags: javascript, flask, fetch

quiero que al introducir un texto en un input se muestre en la pagina y en la consola
hice uno similar en donde se sumaban dos numeros y me salio bien, pero con el texto no sale bien
el backend es con flask y estoy usando javascript puro, si tambien me quieren hacer una recomendacion u observacion me ayudaria mucho

```
if(window.location == "http://127.0.0.1:5000/trap"){

const fun = document.querySelector("#fun")

const form = document.querySelector("form");

const results = document.querySelector("#results");
const clearButton = document.querySelector("#clear");
```

cuando oprimo el boton no me muestra error solo se recarga la pagina

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (event)=>{

    fun_value=parse(fun.value)

    let request_options={
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({fun:fun_value})
    }
    fetch('/mtrap', request_options)
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
        results.innerHTML += `<p>${data.fun}</p>`
    })
    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})

    event.preventDefault();

})
```

Este boton es para limpiar los resultados

```
clearButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    results.innerHTML = "";
})
```

}

Comment: En tu manejador del evento `submit`, prueba añadir la siguiente línea al principio: `event.preventDefault();`, para evitar que el formulario sea enviado (es la acción por defecto del botón de envío). De esta forma tendrás el resultado que esperas. Saludos

Comment: Si muhas gracias si me sirvio.

Comment: tambien tuve que quitar el parse()